# Display image inline using Doxygen

Tags: html, image, markdown, documentation, doxygen

I'm using Doxygen to generate an html user manual from markdown files. I'd like to give instructions such as "Click on the [image.png] button" and have the png image appear in the line of text in the generated html.

According to Doxygen's documentation, images can be added as follows:
`\image['{'[option]'}'] <format> <file> ["caption"] [<sizeindication>=<size>]`

The documentation also says that *"Currently only the option inline is supported. In case the option inline is specified the image is placed "in the line", when a caption s present it is shown in HTML as tooltip (ignored for the other formats)."* This sounds like what I want to do.

I've tried several variations of the \image command with no luck. These successfully produce an image, but on its own line:

```
!["caption"](image.png)
\image html image.png "caption"
```

and these commands fail:

```
\image inline html image.png "caption"
\image{inline} html image.png "caption"
```

Does anyone know if it's possible to do what I'm trying to achieve? Am I just getting the syntax wrong?

Comment: Which version are you using (I assume 1.8.15), but please double check with doxygen -v. The version with `\image{inline} html image.png "caption"` should work.

Comment: @albert - I'm using version 1.8.14.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `{inline}` option with the `\image` command is introduced in version 1.8.15
The version:

```
\image{inline} html image.png "caption"
```

does work in 1.8.15.

OP used an older version and will have got warnings like:

> warning: image type inline specified as the first argument of inline
>   is not valid warning: expected whitespace after { command

Comment: Note: you will still need to set the IMAGE_PATH in your Doxyfile even if it is in the same directory, you will need to set `IMAGE_PATH = ./`

Comment: How can you reference this image in the markdown pages?

Comment: I'm not aware of any other possibility than using an explicit `\anchor` and subsequently reference this anchor.

Comment: Based on the comment  I've just pushed a proposed patch to github (pull request 8692, github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/8692).

Comment: Mentioned pull request has been integrated in master on github

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem too. This line fixed it for me:

```
 \image html name.png width=800cm height=600cm
```

Comment: What problem did you have exactly? Which version of doxygen are you using? a width 0f 800cm seems to me a bit large.